Is it true that for all $a \in V$, $T(a)= \sum_{i=1}^r A_{ij} a_i$
Assume that $T$ is a linear operator on $V$, and $\dim(V)=n$. let $a_1, a_2, \dots a_r $ ($r<n$) be a distant eigen vectors
Is it true that for all $a \in V$, $T(a)= \sum_{i=1}^r A_{ij} a_i$? I wasn't able to prove or disprove this by finding a counter example, however I believe this is false.
If $a$ is spanned by $a_1, \dots a_r$ then this can be trivially concluded however if $a$ is not spanned by these vectors then it is hard to say.
The problem with verifying this (or anything that is related to matrices) is that I don't know or have any tools that can do these numerical operations for me so I choose some random $3\times 3$ matrix and hope I can solve the cubic equation to find its eigen values and then hope that it has less than three eigen vectors. Because of this I wasn't able to verify this claim.
